# Check list from HTML and parse to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, google-sheets, automation

I have an apparel list in Google Sheets with the following columns:

[image: Apparel List Empty]

This is only a little part of it. It actually has over 9K items. So here's the thing, I have to manually search each of those legacy numbers on a HTML list provided by the client, which looks like this:

[image: Platform List]

As you can see on the last column, there are some texts like "Completed", "Customer Review", etc. Those values have to be parsed on the google sheet "Status" column. After reviewing some orders and copying those values, the sheet looks like this:
[image: Completed List]

Now, imagine doing this process individually with 9K+ orders, it's a pain in the ass. So I thought there could be a way to automatize this, maybe parsing the values from the HTML through some Javascript to a CSV or anything similar. I've been doing some research but haven't found anything. I'm not asking you to do the job for me. I'm looking for a hint to start this correctly, as it would make a lot easier and faster the work.

Note: this "automatization" isn't a task or job requested to me, I'm a designer (with some programming background) and I have to do the manual process with a deadline, so I thought I could try and speed up this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [`IMPORTHTML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339) so you can add the data from the HTML list on a different tab in Google sheets and then perform an [INDEX MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) or an [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) to get the data that you need.

There are many ways to compare the data that you need using different formulas, if you can create a demo sheet we could help you finding a formula that could perform the query of the data that you need. As a friendly reminder always try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. That way we can provide better insights about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I'll be doing some testing with IMPORTHTML.  About comparing the data, basically I have to compare a Legacy ID (from the sheet, first column) with the ones from the html table (second column). If it's the same legacy # then retrieve the value from the last table column and parse it to the sheet.

Comment: Exactly, as you want to make a comparison there are several ways to do it, however the main goal was to use the IMPORTHTML function so you can have the data into the spreadsheet that way you don't have to be manually checking the inputs as they will be already added to the sheet and it will be a matter of retrieving the specific Legacy ID as shown in your example.

Comment: I've been messing around with IMPORTHTML and it worked with other websites. Unfortunately, the page where the table is located, has an authentication login before the table actually shows up. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: It would be good to check if the data can be retrieved some other way as the IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML functions that are mostly used to scrap web data can't retrieve any data if a login is required to access the information, is the data that you need only available through the HTML list only? The client should have a way to export the data somewhere else I guess.

Comment: I had to use another method but I got to make it work! I'll post the solution later. Thanks for your suggestions, INDEX MATCH did help a lot!